# How does the Action Wiggle Node works in animation nodes?

Tags: animation-nodes

I haven´t been able to make work the Action Wiggle node in AN 2.1.5. Can someone please provide a working example on how to make this node work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since AN 2.1.5 is still a work in progress version. The node may not be final and documentation is missing.

Here is a working example. Hope it helps you.
You need to add and define the affected channel path.

- location
- scale
- rotation_euler

[image]

Comment: Thanks. That was all that I need.

Comment: @JorgeLosillaMartínez "That was all that I need", but yet you offer a bounty?

Comment: Yeah. I wanted to thank your response but it seems impossible to it backwards  @WhatAMesh